# Is there a way to automate declaring variables in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object, variable-declaration

I'm learning PHP and working in Codeigniter. I feel that I am typing similar things over again (duplicating work) when I am making data arrays and declaring the variables I need for functions.

Here is an example:

```
  //MAKE ARRAY OF USER ANSWERS TO QUESTIONS
    $dropdowndata = array
    (   'user_socialhour' => $this->input->post('socialhour'),
        'user_socialpm' => $this->input->post('socialpm'),
        'user_eventhour' => $this->input->post('eventhour'),
        'user_eventpm' => $this->input->post('eventpm');

    //DECLARE THE VARIABLES I NEED FOR FUNCTIONS
         $user_socialhour = $this->input->post('socialhour');
        $user_socialpm = $this->input->post('socialpm');
        $user_eventhour = $this->input->post('eventhour');
        $user_eventpm = $this->input->post('eventpm');

     $calculateddata = array
    ('user_mornafteve' => $this->mornafteve($user_socialhour, >$user_socialpm), 'user_beforeafter' => $this->beforeafter($user_socialpm, >$user_eventpm, $user_socialhour, $user_eventhour));
```

I am looking for a way to automate the declaration of all the variables in  the dropdowndata array. I am looking for something like, for each key, declare the variables according to the following pattern.

Does this exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ye,

```
foreach($dropdowndata as $key=>$value) {
    $$key = $this->input->post(substr($key, 5))
}
```

But not sure why you need these as variables at all... why not just use as:

```
//MAKE ARRAY OF USER ANSWERS TO QUESTIONS
    $dropdowndata = array(   
        'user_socialhour' => $this->input->post('socialhour'),
        'user_socialpm' => $this->input->post('socialpm'),
        'user_eventhour' => $this->input->post('eventhour'),
        'user_eventpm' => $this->input->post('eventpm');

    $calculateddata = array(
        'user_mornafteve' => $this->mornafteve($dropdowndata['user_socialhour'], $dropdowndata['user_socialpm']), 
        'user_beforeafter' => $this->beforeafter($dropdowndata['user_socialpm'], $dropdowndata['user_eventpm'], $dropdowndata['user_socialhour'], $dropdowndata['user_eventhour']));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want... but you can turn array keys into local variables...

```
$array = ['x' => 1, 'y' => 2];
extract($array);
var_dump($x);
var_dump($y);
```

> php test.php
>
> int(1)
>
> int(2)

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: Awesome, rchh, that's it! I particularly like the second option, which I didn't know was a possibility. This will help me streamline my code enormously....I had a feeling i was being way too verbose about it. I marked this answer as correct. Thank you!